# Big-O of loop that has math.pow in condition

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

For the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.pow(n, 3); i++){
    ...some code here...
}
```

Does the loop body execute N times? Because as N increases, the number of times Math.pow gets called. Or am I thinking about Big-O wrongly as it may also be logn because the math.pow makes the loop run faster similar to a binary search?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about exactly. The loop has exactly `n^3` iterations. Which is, of course, in `O(n^3)`. Supposed the body runs in constant time. Or are you changing `n` inside the loop? The condition is evaluated after each iteration again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop iterates from 0 to *n*<sup>3</sup>−1. If the code inside the loop executes in constant time, and doesn't modify *i* or *n*, then the overall runtime is *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: ... provided that *n* is not modified by the loop body, of course.

Comment: So if the comparison changes from 3 to i <= Math.pow(n, 1.5), it would run O(n^1.5)?

Comment: @Chris essentially, yes. It's O(n^1.5) **if** the contents of the loop are O(1).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex in the loop body, what if there is i = i * 2?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to modify loop variables inside a loop. If *i* or *n* are modified then the analysis changes.

Comment: @JohnKugelman What would the time complexity be if there was a modified var i=i*2; ?

Comment: @Chris then you essentially have `for (…; i < Math.pow(n, 1.5); i = 2*i + 1);`. Doing the math, this is essentially O(log_2(n^1.5)) or O(log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you are asking for. In terms of the loop, it will operate n^3 times, therefore giving O(n^3). If you are asking about just the Math.pow function on its own, Math.pow(x, y) will have complexity of O(log y), so O(1) in this case.

Comment: [`Math.pow` is a method on `double`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-), which uses an O(1) hardware instruction regardless of `x` and `y`.

Comment: What would the runtime be if there was a modified var in loop body i = i *2?

Answer (score 1):

The value of n does not change in the loop, so the loop executes only n^3 times. 
Therefore the complexity is O(n^3).